# how make button tag with different class in JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

i already know how to make it repeated button tag in Jquery.

but i didn't know how to make it button tag with **Different Classes** repeatedly.

Is there a way to create button tags repeatedly with different classes?

this is sample code

```
<div class="btndiv">
    <button class="btn"></button>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
   $(".btndiv").append("<button class='btn'></button>");
})
```

i want different class button tag automatically when i button click.

Comment: share what you try so far?

Comment: ok i edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```js
var i=1;
$(".btn").click(function(){
   $(".btndiv").append("<button class='btn"+i+"'>Button "+i+"</button>");
   i++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btndiv">
    <button class="btn">Create Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below by adding count variable. Each time a class name with count is added.

```
<div class="btndiv">
    <button class="btn">CLick</button>
</div>

$(function(){ 
     var i = 0;

    $(".btn").click(function(){
       $(".btndiv").
       append('<button class="className '+i+++'">'+ 'Click'+'</button>');
    })
 });
```